# Subversion/Maven changes in snapshot since last release

Tags: maven, svn, pom.xml, maven-release-plugin, parent-pom

I expect this is a common issue, but one I am not aware of a sensible solution to.

We have adopted the procedure where all local dependent modules are moved straight back to SNAPSHOT once the release has been done. Time passes and we come to do a new release.

When we come to release we need to make a decision on whether a particular module has had any changes or not. If not, we dont need to update release the dependent snapshot and we can simply build against the previous release version as nothing has changed.

The difficulty in this process is establishing whether anything *has* actually changed since the last release or not. The only way I can imagine establishing this is to look in the subversion logs to see if any significant change has been checked in since the last release, and if it has then we need to release the dependent module. If it hasnt, we are ok to use the previous released version. This seems very labour intensive to me.

Is there a plugin or a better way to achieve this?

Comment: First are those modules independant and should be released at different time or are those module build an application and could be released to the same time?

Comment: Hi. Each module has its own lifespan and may or may not have changes linked to a particular release. I do not want to release a new version of a module if nothing in that module has changed.